# how to retrieve data from user control textbox in form textbox or label in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here I make a user control and there is a textbox in that control. Now, I want the value of that textbox will be displayed in label or form textbox code, below is user control side.

```
public string TextBox1Value
{
    get
    {
        return tbEndDate.Text;
    }
    set { tbEndDate.Text = TextBox1Value; }
}
```

Below code is form side trying to fetch the textbox value of usercontrol in form label

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label1.Text = calander1.TextBox1Value.ToString();
    }
```

The problem is that whenever I click on button the label becomes blank!

Comment: Are you not getting the value?

Comment: Is your code not working?

Comment: Are you getting any value if you just do this `Label1.Text = tbEndDate.Text`?

Comment: actually when ever i am going to click on button the label become blank

Comment: what is your question ??

Comment: as i depicted above that i am trying to get the value of user control  textbox and display that value in label in web page..

Comment: Store the value in `Session` and fetch in on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `value` keyword in `set{}` routine

```
public string TextBox1Value
{
    get
    {
        return tbEndDate.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        // tbEndDate.Text = TextBox1Value; //<-- you need to use "value" keyword here
        tbEndDate.Text = value;
    }
}
```